# django_filters - FilterView - how to build URL

Tags: python, django, django-filters

**views.py**

```
import django_filters
class Au_selFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    test= django_filters.BooleanFilter(label="prova")
    class Meta:
        model = au_sel
        fields = ['tipo', 'stato']
```

**urls.py**

```
    url(r'^flist/$', FilterView.as_view(filterset_class= views.Au_selFilter)),
```

when I go to:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/flist/

I get all of the data in au_sel model, but how can I add *the filter*?

I've tried to:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/flist/?tipo=xx
>    or
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/flist?stato=xx

but a blank page appear, also debug_toolbar seems to be missing on this url...

Ok I'm off: the fiter works fine, I was passing to it wrong values, if you have a manytomany field, maybe it will use *id*

Comment: What's the question or did you answer it yourself?

Comment: I've solved myself, but this may be useful for some one else